# Why does CMake convert some of my TARGET_INCLUDE_LIBRARY entries from absolute paths to -L / -l linker arguments

Tags: linux, linker, cmake, cross-compiling, ncurses

I'm trying to use **ncurses** and its sister library **forms** in an application that is being cross-compiled for an ARM-based Zynq platform.

The linker dies, complaining that it can't find `libncurses.so.5`
I have searched around for this error, and the solution is usually involves installing a 32 bit version of libncurses. However, in this case, this is a 32 bit distribution to begin with so there is no reason for me to believe that this is a 32/64 bit thing.

This is baffling, because CMake does initally seem to be able to find the libraries in question:

I created "FindNCurses" and "FindForm" cmake modules to find these libraries. The modules use `find_path` with some proposed search paths. These paths point to my target rootfs (i.e. the staged rootfs for the system I will be copying this application to).

Using message() statements in CMakeLists.txt, I can see that the "FindXYZ" modules did populate the `NCURSES_LIBRARIES` and `FORM_LIBRARIES` variables with absolute paths to the relevant .so files.

However, in the `link.txt` files that are generated, I see that the absolute path for the ncurses library .so has been replaced with a combination of -L / -l

The absolute path to the forms library remains unchanged.

Thus I expect this:

```
/project/linux/software/build/linux/rootfs/stage/usr/lib/libncurses.so
/project/linux/software/build/linux/rootfs/stage/usr/lib/libform.so
```

But I actually get this:

```
-L/project/linux/software/build/linux/rootfs/stage/usr/lib
-lncurses
/project/linux/software/build/linux/rootfs/stage/usr/lib/libform.so
```

Digging deeper, I see that `.../stage/usr/lib` only contains `libncurses.so`, but not `libncurses.so.5`. Furthermore, `libcurses.so` does not seem to be an actual .so file, but an ld script:

```
INPUT(libncurses.so.5 AS_NEEDED(-ltinfo))
```

Is this a normal thing to do? I guess that's where the mention of "libncurses.so.5" came from, but the libncurses.so.5 file is definitely absent. It can be found in `.../stage/lib` however (no /usr)

libform.so and libform.so.5 do exist under `.../stage/usr/lib` and under `.../stage/lib`

`libform.so` contains actual code, not an ld script.

Am I using the CMake's find process incorrectly?
Or is it my staged Linux rootfs not created correctly (i.e. should libncurses.so.5 actually exist under usr/lib)? I'm using automated tools (Petalinux) from Xilinx, so I don't have much control about how this is all assembled.

Any insights as to what might be going on? Should I copy the `/lib/libncurses.so.5` files to `/usr/lib/`?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I tried copying the libcurses.so.5 file from /lib to /usr/lib and everything compiles now. I will need to wait until I get to work to try it on the target system. The directory I made the change in is autogenerated so this is definitely not a long-term solution.

**EDIT 2**: I am using CMake 2.8.11, but there is no reason to prevent me from upgrading. I would need to coordinate the upgrade with my other teammates, but that's a possibility.

**EDIT 3**: Some progress:
I upgraded to CMAKE 3.3.x, but did not seem to fix the problem. 
I tried using the built-in "Find Curses" module, it seems that I needed to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to point to the local copy of the target system's rootfs. It appears to be finding the libncurses.so in what I think is the right place (PREFIX/usr/lib)

I'm still seeing CMAKE convert the absolute path to the ncurses library to a -l/-L combo:

```
-lncurses
-L(CORRECT PREFIX)/usr/lib
```

- libncurses.so is in PREFIX**/usr/lib**
- libncurses.so contains the string "INPUT(libncurses.so.5 AS_NEEDED(-ltinfo))"
- libncurses.so.5 is in PREFIX**/lib**

*How is the linker supposed to know that it needs to go down to PREFIX/lib to find the .so.5 file?*

Should they be in the same directory?
It seems to me that the path stated in libncurses.so should point correctly to the .so.5 file. I tried changing the path to an absolute path that points to the .so.5 file and it also works.

It seems like the only solution I have found for this is to make sure that the .so.5 file is where the .so file says it should be (makes sense, but by default, this Petalinux distro seems to put the files in different directories for some reason).

- Copying the .so.5 file to /usr/lib works
- Changing the path in the .so file to an absolute path under /lib works

I'm starting to wonder if this is just a bug in the Petalinux tools/distro version that I am using...

Thanks

Comment: The link thing with so libraries is common and probably not the source of your problem. Can you show us the actual error message you get? And can you run `make VERBOSE=1` to see how the compiler/linker is invoked? Does it really link to the ARM library or to your system's one (32bit)?

Comment: Cmake already has [findCurses module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCurses.html) for searching `curses`/`ncurses`. Have you tried it instead of handwritten module?

Comment: Is there another CMake target named `ncurses` in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Normally CMake only does the "-L/-l" thing only for its own targets (see CMake policy [CMP0003](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0003.html)). Or you may need to update to CMake 3.3 (see policy [CMP0060](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0060.html)).

Comment: If you update to CMake 3.3, test it on a local machine. Only if this solves your problem, consider switching your project/team. First try the other comments.